# Why NSNumber do not respect locale decimalSeparator

Tags: swift, string, number-formatting, nsnumber

I am using `NumberFormatter` to convert `String` to `NSNumber` with respect of the current locale.

My test locale is Sweden.

So the `decimalSeparator`in my case is ","

This is `NumberFormatter` declaration.

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = .current
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
numberFormatter.isLenient = true
```

Usage.

```
let number = numberFormatter.number(from:"1,01") // 1.01
```

But when I try to convert `NSNumber` back to string.

```
let stringNumber = number?.stringValue // 1.01
```

I receive wrong locale `decimalSeparator`.

Comment: NSNumber knows nothing about locales. NSNumberFormatter has conversion methods for  *both* directions.

Comment: @MartinR but if I am not making mistake Double and Float care about locale ?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: @MartinR yes it is issue with string formatting thx for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `stringValue` to convert the number back to a string you wish to display to the user. Use your `NumberFormatter` to convert the number to a locale friendly string representation.

FYI - there is no need to set the number formatter's `locale` to `.current` since that is the default.